# ¿Qué puedo hacer si me marca error y no veo ningúno?

Tags: arduino, sensor, tinker

Al ingresar el código en Tinkercard (Uso tinkercard ya que es un proyecto de la escuela y aun no tengo los materiales necesarios para realizarlo en físico) me aparece el mismo error de código pero ya lo verifiqué varias veces y no veo el error
Éste es el código completo:

```
int TRIG=11;
int ECHO=10;
int distancia;
int tiempo;
int rojo=1;
int naranja=2;
int amarillo=3;
int verde=4;
int azul=5;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(TRIG, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ECHO, INPUT);
  pinMode(1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(TRIG, HIGH);
  delay(1)
  digitalWrite(TRIG, LOW);
  tiempo=pulseIn(ECHO, HIGH);
  distancia=tiempo/58;
  
  if(distancia=>9 && distancia=<11) {
    digitalWrite(rojo, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(rojo, LOW);
  }
  if(distancia=>19 && distancia=<21){
    digitalWrite(naranja, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(naranja, LOW);
  }
  if(distancia=>29 && distancia=<31){
    digitalWrite(amarillo, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(amarillo, LOW);
  }
   if(distancia=>39 && distancia=<41){
    digitalWrite(verde, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(verde, LOW);
  }
   if(distancia=>49 && distancia=<51){
    digitalWrite(azul, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(azul, LOW);
  }
}
```

Se supone que con ese código deberían prender los LED de distintos colores dependiendo la distancia que estén del Sensor ultrasónico de 4 pines
Para eso use un Arduino Uno R3

Comment: ¿Nos dirás el error o tendremos que adivinarlo? ...

Answer (score 3):

Tienes errores de sintaxis que el IDE te informó clara y apropiadamente:

```
sketch_feb13a:26:3: error: expected ';' before 'digitalWrite'
   digitalWrite(TRIG, LOW);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
sketch_feb13a:30:16: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
   if(distancia=>9 && distancia=<11) {
                ^
sketch_feb13a:30:32: error: expected primary-expression before '<' token
   if(distancia=>9 && distancia=<11) {
```

Tus errores se resumen en:

1. Falta un ";" en la línea 25.
2. Se escribe "<=", no "=<".
3. Se escribe ">=", no "=>".